# bad base64 in android

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate

Hi i am using the following code to parse a certificate details.Everything is fine except a bit problem mentioned below.

```
package android.net.http;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.Certif`enter code here`icate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Base64InputStream;
import android.util.Log;

 public class SslCertificate1Activity extends Activity
 {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

try  {
String text = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"+
    "MIIC/TCCAmagAwIBAgIBKjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBqDEiMCAGA1UEAxMZeG1sZ2F0ZXdheS5p\n"+
    "dHMudXRleGFzLmVkdTEoMCYGA1UECxMfSW5mb3JtYXRpb24gVGVjaG5vbG9neSBTZXJ2aWNlczEq\n"+
    "MCgGA1UEChMhVGhlIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkgb2YgVGV4YXMgYXQgQXVzdGluMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZBdXN0\n"+
    "aW4xDjAMBgNVBAgTBVRleGFzMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzAeFw0wNDA1MDkwNTMwMTBaFw0wNTA1MDQw\n"+
    "NTMwMTBaMIGAMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEOMAwGA1UECBMFVGV4YXMxDzANBgNVBAcTBkF1c3RpbjEq\n"+
    "MCgGA1UEChMhVGhlIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkgb2YgVGV4YXMgYXQgQXVzdGluMRMwEQYDVQQLEwpUb29s\n"+
    "cyBUZWFtMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZDbGllbnQwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAJ6PABjb\n"+
    "zXUkgo29S4uv1Qz9reo1/tP4pkQTGAldSbtA4hVtA/3sjw2+u3kgxYruAi2cXV2k0RPZhsUZjlDk\n"+
    "jMPb/dlY81bD8gqe3lu3ezugJrlArlpfWN6PlufbTjxHSqIA0XD9R5/ZECaUV9dD43K5KdWUCy99\n"+
    "YKDiSwVPO9F5AgMBAAGjXTBbMB0GA1UdDgQWBBRkCCpscEXxXu8Ba67p6zdh13ypjzAfBgNVHSME\n"+
    "GDAWgBR2RsZH2kSY782kBROo92FAWS6sADAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMA4GA1UdDwQHAwUBEiRIkDANBgkq\n"+
    "hkiG9w0BAQQFAAOBgQCtV1NzpdVBs5vyb8yLXNA3hA1LsmE/2QanXG4T3UN93BI4HQzx0idnkN1Y\n"+
    "0RAQ1rjGeQ1pk3l2DWsPi9mTkCGmYs/EMLkKOBee9ad3BIG6sKwXgbgLyNLgda+Y1bo+SIomq/a7\n"+
    "yP92UHMFEegfS/ssECA+Q3hHuU6in3AqLfWH1w==\n"+
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
int startIndex = 0;
String cert = text.substring(startIndex,text.length()); 
    byte[] certBytes = cert.getBytes();
    InputStream in = new Base64InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            certBytes), 0);
CertificateFactory certFact = CertificateFactory.getInstance ("X.509");
    Certificate certGen = certFact.generateCertificate(in); 
    X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) certGen; 
     Log.i("","certificate details:"+x509);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)  
    {
        Log.e("testapp", "exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
    }  
}
 }
```

and I am getting android.util.BASE64DataException:bad base-64 at the foloowing line when I launced debugger:-

```
Certificate certGen = certFact.generateCertificate(in);
```

Seems like there is something wrong with Base64InputStream.Please help in rectifying the Exception.
    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, nothing is wrong with `Base64InputStream`. When in doubt, you should suspect your *own* code of being incorrect rather than everyone else's.

What's wrong is that you're giving Base64InputStream data that ends with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" *after* the padding part.

You should only be passing in the bit *between* "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----".

It looks like you've started thinking about that already here:

```
int startIndex = 0;
String cert = text.substring(startIndex,text.length());
```

... but that code isn't going to do anything - when `startIndex` is 0, `substring` is going to return the whole string...

Personally I'd consider doing the Base64 conversion *first* using the [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class to convert the base64 part of the string (you still need to get the substring) to a `byte[]` and then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` around that.

Comment: Thanks John:COuld you please elaborate how achieve this in form of some code snippet" Base64 conversion first using the Base64 class to convert the base64 part of the string (you still need to get the substring) to a byte[] and then create a ByteArrayInputStream around that".

Comment: @john: Which bit do you not understand? There are three steps: get the substring which is *actually* the base64 data; convert to `byte[]` using `Base64.decode`; create a `ByteArrayInputStream` to wrap the `byte[]`.

Comment: yeah exactly I know how to do this exactly I am doing in this code.Do u have any other way to do it?If so u can post it here.That will be really appreciated.

Comment: @john: No, that's the best way to do it IMO. Why would you want a different way?

Comment: I was just thinking if there is another way possible to get rid of this exception.

Comment: @john: Well the fundamental problem is that you're passing it bad data, just as the exception says. Once you've stripped away the header/footer, your existing code may work - but it's not how I would write it.

Comment: @john: Sorry, I've got better things to do right now. You said: "I know how to do this exactly I am doing in this code" - so why would you need to see my code?

Comment: ok..jon Thanks for your post buddy...hope to have lots of discussion with u in future:)